# What happens if you don't realize sajdah ayah?

Tags: fiqh, sajdat-al-tilaawah

According to Abu Hanafi sajdah tilavah is obligatory. What is the ruling about the one who doesn't realized he just heard sajdah ayat? Can one make lots of tilavah sajdah in one go in order to compensate the ones he might missed and what happens if one makes sajdah more times than he should?

Comment: For the sake of clarity, are you seeking only responses according to the Hanafi school of fiqh (as your opening sentence would suggest?)

Comment: @goldPseudo I wrote it so that people won't just say "it's sunnah, don't worry about it." and leave it at that. I felt the need for letting people know that I know it is obligatory in hanafi madhab. But still, all views are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The majority of scholars said that the tilawah sajdah is sunnah for the reader and the listener **who listens and is intended to hear**, not the listener: He hears without listening is intended

as in Sahih al-Bukhari [1077]:

> عَنْ رَبِيعَةَ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ الْهُدَيْرِ التَّيْمِيِّ ـ
>   قَالَ أَبُو بَكْرٍ وَكَانَ رَبِيعَةُ مِنْ خِيَارِ النَّاسِ عَمَّا
>   حَضَرَ رَبِيعَةُ مِنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قَرَأَ
>   يَوْمَ الْجُمُعَةِ عَلَى الْمِنْبَرِ بِسُورَةِ النَّحْلِ حَتَّى إِذَا
>   جَاءَ السَّجْدَةَ نَزَلَ فَسَجَدَ وَسَجَدَ النَّاسُ، حَتَّى إِذَا
>   كَانَتِ الْجُمُعَةُ الْقَابِلَةُ قَرَأَ بِهَا حَتَّى إِذَا جَاءَ
>   السَّجْدَةَ قَالَ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنَّا نَمُرُّ بِالسُّجُودِ
>   فَمَنْ سَجَدَ فَقَدْ أَصَابَ، وَمَنْ لَمْ يَسْجُدْ فَلاَ إِثْمَ
>   عَلَيْهِ‏.‏ وَلَمْ يَسْجُدْ عُمَرُ ـ رضى الله عنه‏.‏ وَزَادَ نَافِعٌ
>   عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ ـ رضى الله عنهما إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَمْ يَفْرِضِ
>   السُّجُودَ إِلاَّ أَنْ نَشَاءَ‏.‏
>
> Narrated Rabia: Umar bin Al-Khattab recited Surat-an-Nahl on a
>   Friday on the pulpit and when he reached the verse of Sajda he got
>   down from the pulpit and prostrated and the people also prostrated.
>   The next Friday Umar bin Al-Khattab recited the same Sura and when he
>   reached the verse of Sajda he said, "O people! When we recite the
>   verses of Sajda (during the sermon) whoever prostrates does the right
>   thing, yet it is no sin for the one who does not prostrate." And Umar
>   did not prostrate (that day). Added Ibn `Umar "Allah has not made the
>   prostration of recitation compulsory but if we wish we can do it."

And in Sahih Muslim

> عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ، قَالَ رُبَّمَا قَرَأَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ
>   صلى الله عليه وسلم الْقُرْآنَ فَيَمُرُّ بِالسَّجْدَةِ فَيَسْجُدُ بِنَا
>   حَتَّى ازْدَحَمْنَا عِنْدَهُ حَتَّى مَا يَجِدُ أَحَدُنَا مَكَانًا
>   لِيَسْجُدَ فِيهِ فِي غَيْرِ صَلاَةٍ ‏.‏ ...
>
> Ibn 'Umar reported: Sometimes the Messenger of Allah (may peace be
>   upon him) recited the Qur'an, and would pass by (recite) the verse of
>   sajda and performed prostration and he did this along with us, but we
>   were so crowded in his company that none of us could find a place for
>   performing prostration. (and it was done on occasions) other than
>   prayer. Should not for the listener sajdah ayah to prostrate unless if
>   the reader prostrated, because the Prophet (peace be upon him) read to
>   him Zaid ibn Thabit (may Allah be pleased with him) Najm surah didn't
>   prostrate and  prophet didn't prostrate.

Note: Should not for the listener sajdah ayah to prostrate(sajdah) unless if the reader prostrated, because the Prophet (peace be upon him) read to him Zaid ibn Thabit (may Allah be pleased with him) Najm surah didn't prostrate and  prophet didn't prostrate.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you realize or remember you've heard an ayah with a sajdah, you must do sajud (it could be even a day after the event). If you never realized such thing, it doesn't matter.

Forgetfulness is not a sin.